# Use some kind of inheritance with database tables

Tags: mysql, sql, inheritance, enums, create-table

Is it possible (and how can I achieve it) to get some kind of inheritance with database tables?
I intend to have a parent table *X*

```
CREATE TABLE `X` ( 
`xId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`addressId` int(11) NOT NULL, 
`poiType` enum('ParkingPOI','ChargingPOI') NOT NULL, 
`status` enum('AVAILABLE','NOT_AVAILABLE') NOT NULL 
PRIMARY KEY (`aId`), 
KEY `fk_x_address_idx` (`addressId`), 
CONSTRAINT `fk_address` FOREIGN KEY (`addressId`) REFERENCES `addresses` (`addressId`) 
ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=217 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and a child table *B*

```
CREATE TABLE `B` (
`bId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`xId` int(11) NOT NULL', 
`status` enum('AVAILABLE','NOT_AVAILABLE','PARTLY_AVAILABLE') NOT NULL  
PRIMARY KEY (`bId`), 
KEY `aId` (`xId`), 
CONSTRAINT `fk_a` FOREIGN KEY (`xId`) REFERENCES `X` (`xId`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

In table *X* I want to have something like an ENUM with values being inherited from the child table, for instance: AVAILABLE, NOT_AVAILABLE. In this table/column of the parent table (*X*) only these values shall be allowed.
In the child table, however, this ENUM should be extendend so that the values AVAILABE, NOT_AVAILABLE, PARTLY_AVAILABLE shall be possible.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you know what foreign keys are, or have you heard about them at least?

Comment: Why? What do you mean? How does that help me to extend an enum??

Comment: Knowing what foreign keys are implies you have some knowledge about *relational* databases. Knowing about them helps you construct your database model properly. There is no inheritance in relational databases. There are relations. It's not object oriented, it's relational algebra that's being used and that means if you want to achieve something, you need to follow the rules of relational databases. Your model seems inappropriate and I asked whether you know about foreign keys in order to steer you in the right direction.

Comment: Ah! I see. Well, I'm not an SQL Guru but I am basically familiar with SQL, RDBMs, FK, ... I am a Java programmer and I wonder if it is possible to 'implement' something similar like OO inheritance into a relational database. I understand that I have map an object to a relational database table and that I cant use B.status extends X.status... ;-)